# How to deal with "text_field must refer to a character mode column"?

Tags: r, dataframe, corpus

I was just trying to convert my dataframe into a corpus (a very normal procedure) when the following error propped up: **Error in corpus.data.frame(df, text_field = "Text"): text_field must refer to a character mode column**. My dataframe is a normal one with specified columns (*Date* and *Text*). The only "new" thing I did compared to the past is that I read the texts from text files and when trying to read one document I got this **Error in nchar(lev, "w"): invalid multibyte string, element 198**, just because there were some symbols that R could not read.

```
#Read the data from the folder

file.list <- list.files(pattern = '*.txt')

df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_file)

#Convert to a dataframe

df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, df.list)

colnames(df) <- c("Text")

#Create the Corpus

cp <- corpus(df, text_field = "Text")
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
          Date               Text

1   5 January 2000             Text
2   3 February 2000              Text
3   2 March 2000                 Text
4   30 March 2000               Text
5   13 April 2000               text    
6   11 May 2000
```

I have no idea on how to deal with it. Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot

Comment: @akrun that would not solve the conversion to a corpus, would it?

Comment: That one is related to the error you showed `Error in nchar(lev, "w"): invalid multibyte string,`

Comment: @akrun yes, I saw that before but the main issue remains the fact I cannot convert my dataframe into a corpus, thanks

Comment: Perhaps `df$Text` is a factor variable.  Try `df$Text <- as.character(df$Text)` before creating the corpus.

Comment: @AndrewGustar it worked! thanks a lot!